# Python googletrans module not translating

Tags: python, google-translation-api, googletrans

I am using the googletrans module to try and translate between languages as per the below.

```
import time
from googletrans import Translator
translator = Translator()

translate_channel = translator.translate('Canal La Tele Perú', src='es', dest='en')
```

However, this doesn't seem to be attempting any translation at all. It just returns this:

```
Translated(src=en, dest=en, text=Canal La Tele Perú, pronunciation=Canal La Tele Perú, extra_data="{'translat...")
```

...is this module currently working? Have I done something wrong? Version installed is as per the below:

```
pip install googletrans==3.1.0a0
```

Comment: It's just that Canal de Tele Peru is a geographical name and names of places are often not translated

Comment: @PetrL. In fact, interactively Google Translate actually *does* attempt to translate it.

Comment: thank you to the rest of you though...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The script is translating, but the text you've provided is a proper name and even if its translated it looks almost the same.
I've checked it with the code below:

```
from googletrans import Translator
translator = Translator()

translate_channel = translator.translate('Canal La Tele Perú', src='es', dest='en')
translate_channel2 = translator.translate('La defensa y las acciones ofensivas de Alex Dujshebaev dan a Españasu cuarto bronce en unos Juegos tras los de Atlanta 1996, Sydney 2000 y Pekín 2008.', src='es', dest='en')
print(translate_channel)
print(translate_channel2)
```

And the output was like:

```
Translated(src=es, dest=en, text=Channel La Tele Peru, pronunciation=Channel La Tele Peru, extra_data="{'translat...")
Translated(src=es, dest=en, text=The defense and offensive actions of Alex Dujshebaev give Spain its fourth bronze in a Games after those of Atlanta 1996, Sydney 2000 and Beijing 2008., pronunciation=The defense and offensive actions of Alex Dujshebaev give Spain its fourth bronze in a Games after those of Atlanta 1996, Sydney 2000 and Beijing 2008., extra_data="{'translat...")
```

Hope it helped!

Answer (score -2):

I did this

```
from googletrans import Translator
translator = Translator()

translate = translator.translate('روسيا: نرفض الاتهامات الأمريكية "الحرة" بشأن أوكرانيا',  dest='en')

translate1 = translator.translate('مصادر إيرانية: تم التطرق إلى العديد من النقاط الخلافية خلال مؤتمر فيينا',dest='en')

print(translate.text)

print(translate1.text)
```

Output :

```
Russia: We reject "free" US accusations on Ukraine

Iranian sources: Many controversial points were raised during the Vienna 
Conference
```

Comment: This doesn't really address the question.